# Binary operation long vs int

Tags: c#, binary, bit-manipulation

I'm doing DES implementation and I encoutered problem with binary operations.

I can't figure it out why is there 32 bit mask (0xFFFFFFFFL) and why after deleting it, it gives other value.

```
int leftHalf = (int)(input >> 28); 
int rightHalf = (int)(input & 0x0FFFFFFF);

long connectedHalves = ((leftHalf & 0xFFFFFFFFL) << 28) | (rightHalf & 0xFFFFFFFFL);
long notMasked = (leftHalf << 28) | rightHalf;
```

For example:

```
int leftHalf = 1048560
int rightHalf = 109436546

leftHalfBinary =              11111111111111110000
rightHalfBinary =      110100001011101111010000010

leftHalfMasked =  00000000000011111111111111110000
rightHalfMasked = 00000110100001011101111010000010

LeftHalfShifted =                   11111111111111110000 0000000000000000000000000000
LeftHalfMaskedShifted = 00000000000011111111111111110000 0000000000000000000000000000
```

It looks like to give the same result, but for this example:

```
connectedHalves = 281470791179906
notMasked = 109436546
```

Why?

Code:

https://github.com/poltak/DataEncryptionStandard/blob/master/src/jpsam3hklam9/des/RoundKeyGenerator.java

method: long[] generateRoundKeys(long input)

Comment: You claim to write C#, but that link goes to a file with "java" extension. Anyhow, that link is misplaced, you should put the code (reduced to a [mcve]) into the question.

Comment: Any reason why you're reimplementing DES in C# instead of using the existing class in .NET?

Comment: Any reason for using DES at all? Given that it has been considered insecure for many years...

Comment: The :L t the end indicates the number 32 bit number is stored in a 64 bit operator.  Be careful of sign extensions.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I must implement it as schoolwork

Comment: @jdweng How does it changes the result?

Comment: It likely just promotes the int to a long.

Comment: @PetSerAl Thanks a lot! I get it now! If it was only int it overflows with << 28. Thank you all of you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is int it overflows with << 28.